# Where is the gnome-shell-extension configuration file?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm searching the config file that says which extensions are active beacause i want take it in /etc/skel directory.
also i'm searching too the file of theme configuration (that says which theme is active)

Answer (score 1):

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Answer (score 1):

open dconf editor and find key

> org > gnome > shell > extensions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use skel for this:

1. Edit `/etc/default/useradd` uncomment the skel line to activate.
2. Copy the following folders to `/etc/skel: config;  .local; .pki`
3. Only the new users will take your configuration

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will help in all aspects of your question but have you tried the

[Gnome Tweak Tool](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool#Bug_reports)

It will definitely show you which theme is active plus it has the following features.

- Install and switch gnome-shell themes
- Switch gtk/icon/cursor themes
- Switch window manager themes

Change

- The user-interface and titlebar fonts
- Icons in menus and buttons
- Behavior on laptop lid close
- Shell font size
- File manager desktop icons
- Titlebar click action
- Shell clock to show date
- Font hinting and antialiasing

There is also an indepth article that I have linked to below that explains customizing the GNOME Shell. It explains how the [GConf](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) CORBA-based configuration system is no longer used and has been replaced by [GSettings](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GSettings.html) which it goes on to explain in detail.

[Customizing the GNOME Shell article](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2011/03/customizing-the-gnome-3-shell.html)